# How to change size of text in ion-input

Tags: css, ionic-framework, sass, ionic4

I've a ionic+angular application. In a page, I've a `ion-input`, which is kind of the main entry point of my app:

```
  <div id="topSection" style="width: 100%;">
    <ion-card style="display: flex;" id="searchBox" class="ion-margin">
      <ion-menu-button></ion-menu-button>
      <ion-input type="search" placeholder="Search"></ion-input>
    </ion-card>
  </div>
```

I need it to be a little bit bigger.

I tried to set it in my SCSS:

```
input {
  font-size: 1.8rem !important;
}
```

but it has zero effect. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ion-input` instead of `input`.

```
ion-input {
  font-size: 2.8rem;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add id to input and then try to change it with scss by referencing the id

Comment: The thing is that the ion-input contains the input that should be changed. I tried to but id="searchbox" and #searchbox as css selector, but same result